# Sporadical change of permissions of file being edited

Tags: files

I have a strange behavior - sometimes while editing, permissions of `.rs` files are changed from 0644 to 0755. I'm not sure if it is specific for `rust-mode` or not as so far it is the only mode I regularly use. The most annoying thing is that it happens absolutely randomly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What causes files to automatically become executable

Emacs auto-sets the file permissions to `0755` when the following 2 conditions meet:

1. The file has hash-bang/shebang `#!` at the start of file.
2. The following is added to `init.el` to take effect globally or in particular major modes.

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p)
```

I use this to auto-add execute permissions to my shell and perl scripts.

I think that the `0755` permission is auto set for you only for the files that have something like `#!/usr/bin/env rustx` in the beginning of the file and you have the above hook added globally or only for `rust-mode`.

#### Customizing the hook for a particular major mode

Below will remove the `executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p` function from the `after-save-hook` only when `rust-mode-hook` is activated.

```
(defun my-rust-mode-customizations()
  (remove-hook 'after-save-hook #'executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p :local))
(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook 'my-rust-mode-customizations)
```

*I would recommend keeping this hook at least for the shell script modes.*

Comment: Ohh, that's definitely is the case by a coincidence. I mean rust files might have compiler "settings" like `#![allow(dead_code)]` and so on. So while it is technically not the shebang, emacs can't see the difference as checks just for `#!`. And that hook is enabled globally as I use `Prelude`. Is there a way to disable that hook just for `rust-mode`?

Comment: @ValeriiHiora I have updated my answer with how to customize that hook for rust-mode.